# Get N amount of results per category and filter every third result by a row

Tags: mysql, sql

I extraced some data of my tables to help you reproduce my problem.
The SQL is here (The SQL is adjusted to my current problem, so I didn't include all columns, or all data, because it's not needed)

http://tzfrs.de/dev/test.sql

Now, what I'm doing is the following. I want to get 6 pois per category. This works with the following query

```
SELECT x.id, x.fsqPoi, x.name, cpc.catName, cpc.className 
FROM (
    SELECT bp.id, bp.categoryId, bp.fsqPoi, bp.name, 
        CASE WHEN bp.categoryId = @type 
            THEN @rownum := @rownum + 1 
            ELSE @rownum := 1 
        END AS rank, 
    @type := bp.categoryId FROM (
        select * from pois WHERE cityId = "25" order by id
    ) bp JOIN (
        SELECT @rownum := 0, @type := NULL
    ) r ORDER BY categoryId ) x INNER JOIN poi_categories cpc ON cpc.id = x.categoryId 
WHERE x.rank <= 6 ORDER BY x.categoryId
```

This returns me 6 pois for every category from the poi table. You can adjust the number of pois per category by defining the number at `WHERE x.rank <= XXX`.

The problem I'm currently stuck with is the following.
As you can see, I have the column `fsqPoi` which indicates if the POI has been gathered from Foursquare or not.

I want, that, every first, fourth and seventh POI MUST be a POI from Foursquare. POI 2,3,5,6,8 and 9 can be random, meaning, they can be from Foursquare but don't have to.

This is where I'm stuck. I don't know how to adjust my query to make this work, and I don't know if that does even work. I would greatly appreciate if you could help me out there. Muchas Gracias!